# Maya Custom HUD with python api

Tags: python, api, maya, hud

i wanted to create a custom heads up display like the maya resolution gate for my tool that i could control it with my window.

i try using MPxDrawOverride and create what i want, but ...

1. i see MHUDRender class in the python api documentation, but can't find how use this class. try several ways without a result.any suggestion
2. for the hud that i created, i use MPxLocatorNode , so for this hud to work i should create the node and because of that i have a transform node in the outliner.

is there a way that i can create my custom HUD without create the node?
should i use MHUDRender?
i create several MPxCommand, so that i can control the hud with my ui. is this the right way?

[Custom HUD with MPxDrawOverride](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6He3A.jpg)

[transform node of the hud in the outliner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmuuY.jpg)

Comment: Hi Amin, welcome to SO. Please provide any code you already tried since without we cannot give any hints... have a look here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .

Comment: if you are looking hud customization, there is snoy pictures reticles code that could help you : https://code.google.com/archive/p/imageworks-maya-reticle/source/default/source

Answer (score 1):

If you search of a way to manipulate the HUD without a plugin, take a look at the *headsUpDisplay()* command.